# div loading is not proper while using ajax

Tags: ajax

I have to load a div with a list of check boxes using ajax.  I have writen ajax code to fetch the string containing the list of check boxes.`

```
        document.getElementById("roleCheckBoxes").innerHTML="";

        $('#roleCheckBoxes').append(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
```

the data are fetching properly but the display alone not reflecting the string which I gave instead it displays a the list of check boxes with  all checked.

Comment: You need to provide more code from the actual AJAX function that's fetching the data and also of the HTML.

Comment: are you using jQuery? (I think so because of `$('#roleCheckBoxes')` )

Comment: If you *are* using jQuery, wouldn't a simple `load()` call on the extended element suffice? http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the checkboxes in the HTML you get contain checked="true"?